# "This page isn’t working" error when clicking on a link in Inbox or Achievements tab

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks

When I click on Inbox or Achievement tab links on Stack Overflow, it does not load the page and shows: "This page isn’t working". For example, I'm redirected to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/75189763?noredirect=1. When I change HTTP to HTTPS manually, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular link is working for me.

As you stated in  your question the issue resolves itself when you switch to the https protocol. This indicates it is an issue between you and the Stack Exchange network. There have been previous reports where either browser plugins, anti-virus/firewall applications, rogue ISP's or even national firewalls play tricks with the content being sent, causing all kind of weird errors.

On the plus side: The switch to [default HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) on Stack Overflow is [due on Monday](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/864967605584625665) (<s>give or take 6 to 8 days</s> nope, they [made it on time](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/)) so that would probably resolve these kind of issues for now. Until new ways have been established to interfere with secure traffic :/

So if switching to HTTPS solves your issue or if you have an option to use a different network path (other ISP, Mobile, VPN, Tor) use that. There is nothing SE can do to resolve the issue, except the defaulting to HTTPS.